# Center taskbar icons with the registry

Tags: python, registry, center, taskbar, regedit

I would like to position the icons on my taskbar windows 10 in the center of the desktop.
I know the famous TaskbarX does it but I don't know how to do it in python, could someone explain to me or give me the path in the registry to modify please

[Example of center icons taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1tTN.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On **Windows 10**, you **can't center icons just by modifying the Windows Registry**.

But on **Windows 11 you just modify** `TaskbarAl` (0 = left, 1 = centered) value in `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`.

What TaskbarX and other similar tools do for Windows 10 and prior versions, is to calculate the taskbar icons location using accessibility functions like UIAutomation or MSAA.

[image]

As shown in the picture above, using `UI Accessibility Checker` tool by Microsoft, this is showing the MSAA tree of the `explorer.exe` process, specially that instance that holds the `taskbar`.

First, find the taskbars instances, using [EnumWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) and pick those beloging to `explorer.exe` process that has as Win Class Name "Shell_TrayWnd" (for primary monitor) and "Shell_SecondaryTrayWnd" (for the other monitors). Once you found them, using that tool as a guide, find the exact running applications list in that accessibility tree, for each taskbar instance (main monitor and secondary monitors). Once found the exact location of the taskbar list icons, pick the **first one's left position** and then the **last one's right position**. With that coordinates you will get its real width inside taskbar window, and using [SetWindowPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) modify its position in its taskbar area using its child windows container.

[image]

In the previous picture, you can see the hierarchy of child Windows inside the main taskbar's **Shell_TrayWnd** window handle, the child that contains the running applications is named **ReBarWindow32** which has its own coordinates within that taskbar window, you just **modify it** using a timer or a shell event whenever a new process is started, or existing one is closed, or switched to another virtual desktop, and maybe other events, all that in order to **re-adjust its location** (centering in your case).

Normally, using timers will be polling the system unnecessarily, it is recommended to use the shell messages that Windows taskbar itself relies on, as mentioned here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20201228-00/?p=104610 you register your process as a shell message client or hook the shell message https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks, that depends on you.

You can take a look a PowerToys source code, specially the module ShortCutGuide, that shows the taskbar's icon location with numbers. https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/blob/master/src/modules/ShortcutGuide/ShortcutGuide/tasklist_positions.cpp just find a way to port it to Python and proceed as mentioned above.

I repeat, **Windows 10, doesn't offer that centering functionality out of the box** unlike Windows 11.

If you see the last picture, that snapshot belongs to a child window hierarchy in **Windows 11's taskbar**, but if you'll compare to your Windows 10, 7, 8, etc. (using UUSpy tool or Spy++) you will notice that this picture shows extra child windows, specially using `Xaml` string in its class names. Those are **new children that now holds not only the task list, but the Start menu button, search, widget, etc**. they're not found in Windows 10 or previous versions. However, **Windows 11 still keeps the older list child window** "ReBarWindow32" (that one used in previous Windows versions)  **but it is hidden** in favor of the new ones, and I guess they will remove it in the future, since this new one does the centering and animations when new apps are launched or closed, etc.